# How to Pull Wordpress Blog Titles and Dates into a .NET Page

Tags: .net, wordpress, date, title

On one of our websites i need to pull in the latest three blog titles and dates from a wordpress blog in our site onto our homepage.  I know how to do this using .php but the site is currently in .NET and needs to stay in .net – i've setup a test page here: http://spacesaverscommunity.com/Default-New.aspx

On the right side you'll see "Other Community News" – How can i pull the titles and dates of the latest three posts from their blog and display them in that box on the homepage? (spacesaverscommunity.com/blog/)

Is this possible using .net? can i pull from an rss feed?

any advice much appreciated! thanks.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Do you not know how to request a page (use the `WebClient` class)? Do you not know how to parse the HTML once you've received it (check out Html Agility Pack). Yes, you can pull from an RSS feed. Use `WebClient` to get the page and then either `XmlReader` or LINQ to XML.

Comment: Hi @JimMischel, Unfortunately i am not versed in .net programming too well and do not know how to parse the html  or request the page using WebClient.  Again, in php i've done this many times but am not versed in .net at all.  any code examples you know of or know what to put in the code to get this latest 2 titles and their 2 dates accordingly from the blog page? even if i just pulled the title, that'd be fine, but ideally both. thanks so much, aaron

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Hookpress](http://mitcho.com/blog/projects/hookpress-webhooks-for-wordpress/) which basically offers webhooks. So you could fetch your feed from there.

For a short introduction, take a look at this video: http://player.vimeo.com/video/5905102